# Check if the system of equations have a solution

Tags: c++, algorithm

Question: 
There are `N` variables x<sub>1</sub>, x<sub>2</sub>, x<sub>3</sub>, ...... x<sub>N</sub>.
There are `M` triplets such that triple `{i,j,c}` indicate that x<sub>i</sub> = x<sub>j</sub> + c and so each triplet denote an equation. Check if the system of equations have atleast one solution.

My idea: 
I considered the system of equations as a graph of `N` nodes labelled from 1 to N. If `{i,j,c}` is a triplet then, `i->j` is an edge with `weight c` and `j->i` is an edge with `weight -c`. With 0 as the source, I applied Bellman Ford algorithm to detect any negative cycles. If there is any positive sum cycle, then there must also be a negative sum cycle, which can be traced with Bellman Ford.

Following is the code

```
#include<iostream>
#include<bits/stdc++.h>
using namespace std;

#define INF (1<<30)    
int main(){
    int T;
    cin>>T;
    while(T--){
        int N;int M;
        cin>>N;cin>>M;
        vector<vector<int>> edges;
        for (int i=0;i<M;++i){
            int first;int second;int third;
            cin>>first;cin>>second;cin>>third;
            first--;second--;
            edges.push_back({first,second,third});
            edges.push_back({second,first,-third});
        }
        vector<int> distances(N,INF);
        distances[0] = 0;
        for (int i=1;i<=N;++i){
            for (int j=0;j<edges.size();++j){
                int from = edges[j][0];
                int to = edges[j][1];
                int weight = edges[j][2];
                if (distances[from]+weight<distances[to]){
                    distances[to] = distances[from] + weight;
                }
            }
        }
        int flag = 0;
        for (int j=0;j<edges.size();++j){
            int from = edges[j][0];
            int to = edges[j][1];
            int weight = edges[j][2];
            if (distances[from]+weight<distances[to]){
                flag = 1;
                break;
            }
        }
        if (flag==1){
            cout << "NO" << endl;
        }
        else{
            cout << "YES" << endl;
        }
    }
}
```

Is the idea correct? I am unable to generate test cases against the above logic. But, the code failed to give correct output for many test cases.

Can somebody point out the mistake.

Thank you

Comment: The idea looks reasonable, there might be bugs in the implementation.

Comment: @n.1.8e9-where's-my-sharem. ok then, I'll update the post with the code. Is that ok?

Comment: It is OK but please make it a [mcve] to permit anyone compile and test it with minimum effort.